# Meaning of From statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a sample windowsform app, which print reports when the user perform a double click in a row of a data grid view.

After troubleshooting some issue with query ecc, I run in a strange `from` statement which i've never seen.

Below the statement:

```
SELECT some_tables
FROM table1 table2 inner join table3 table4 on table2.id = table4.id
```

This statament is the result of a working query which I caught by using SQL profiler, I need to do this because the previous query didn't retrive the right data.

I've already searched the statement on the internet but without success, so in details what it do?

Comment: `table2` is an alias for `table1`, and `table4` is an alias for `table3`. I suspect that the above is an overly simplification as no (sane) person would really alias objects like that.  (Good) Aliasing common and helps make very readable SQL.

Comment: @FredrikSchön that SQL is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yeah, it was I who misread. :) That comment must have been up for like 2 seconds, before I deleted it. You're quick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I just saw @Larnu said the same thing I did, she is correct^^

What is happening here is the use of an `alias`, [you can read about them here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-alias/)

```
FROM table1 table2 inner join table3 table4 on table2.id = table4.id
```

Is using an alias, where `table2` is an alias for `table1`, and `table4` is an alias for `table3`.

You can make the association that:
`table2 = table1`
`table4 = table3`

So that statement could also be written:

```
FROM table1 inner join table3 on table1.id = table3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `table2` and `table4` are aliases (usually shorter names) for the tables `table1` and `table3`.
2. The `inner join` means that the records of the two tables are combined pairwise where  `table2.id` must match `table4.id`.

Example:

```
table1
id  description
--  -----------
 1  Apple
 2  Orange
 3  Pear

table2
id  name
--  -----
1   Peter
1   Sue
2   Marc
```

The query

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.description, b.name
FROM
    table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b
        ON a.id = b.id
```

Result

```
id  description  name
--  -----------  ----
 1  Apple        Peter
 1  Apple        Sue
 2  Orange       Marc
```